# Login System : Issues with Session Start

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a login system which checks for the correct login details like below :

```
    <?php
    @session_start();
    require_once "connection.php";
    $Username=$_POST['uname'];
    $Password=$_POST['pass'];

    $encrypt_password=md5($Password);
    //echo $encrypt_password; 

    $Username=stripslashes($Username);
    $Password=stripslashes($Password);
    $Username = mysql_real_escape_string($Username);
    $Password = mysql_real_escape_string($Password);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM loginlist WHERE username='$Username' and password='$encrypt_password'";
    $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $Count=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($Count == 1)
    {
        session_register(myusername);
        session_register(mypassword);
        $_SESSION['uname']=$Username;
        $_SESSION['pass']=$Password;

        header("location:controlpanel.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'wrong user name or password';
    }
?>
```

if the login details are correct it will transfer to the controlpanel.php, I have the below code at the start of controlpanel.php

```
    @session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['uname']))
       echo"<script>window.location='thisisthesystem.php';</script>";
    else
```

but every time I try to login (with correct login details) it throws me back to the login page. Please let me know what's going on wrong there :

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using if(!empty($_SESSION['uname'])) or  if(isset($_SESSION['uname'])).

Comment: Why are you using `@` in front of `session_start();`. And check you DB field `password`, is it md5 encrypted?

Comment: could you please insert the below code after session_start and tell me the output? print_r(_SESSION);exit. I have one doubt also, why are you using @ infront of sesion_start?

Comment: ok @BimalKumar let me try, I don't know why I use @ there, the code was ready, shall I erase the @?

Comment: echo $Count` and confirm that query is working fine. `@` is used for error suppression

Comment: @BimalKumar this is what I got Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: @sinto  I removed the @ the error is still there, and yes the DB field password is md5 encrypted there, no issues there.

Comment: So you have error on using `session_start();`?

Comment: @MustafaAzad don't use session_register(), is an obsolete function,   $_SESSION['uname']=$Username; is enough

Comment: Thank you Everyone, It just got fixed, the problem was it was returning false so it entered the Else section.

Comment: @MustafaAzad also, try to avoid using javascript to redirect users back to the login page. It is less secure. Instead write a common login check code in php with redirect() and include that to the top of the page.

Comment: Will do @Ajesh.A.V, thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should lookup at the isset more.

ISSET checks the variable to see if it has been set, in other words, it checks to see if the variable is any value except NULL or not assigned a value. ISSET returns TRUE if the variable exists and has a value other than NULL. That means variables assigned a " ", 0, "0", or FALSE are set, and therefore are TRUE for ISSET.

```
if ( isset($Variable)){
  //this will be true if $Variable will have some value
}else {
//this is false if $Variable will be empty
}
```

So remove **' ! '** From if as I have said in comment section

[See more about Isset](http://www.geekgumbo.com/2010/12/18/php-the-difference-between-isset-and-empty/)